# Getting HDD info only returns C drive info none others. c#

Tags: c#

I am putting together a program that pulls out a bunch of info from a PC and sends it to a server. I am currently working on trying to pull hdd info from the pc that has multiple drives but i can only get it to work with the first drive. Below is the code that pulls out the actual drive info and below that is the code that writes it out to console:

```
public static string CurrentDiskUsage()
    {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
        {
            try
            {

                if (drive.IsReady)
                {
                    double result = 100 * (double) drive.TotalFreeSpace / drive.TotalSize;
                    result = Math.Round(result, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                    string driveInformation = null;
                    driveInformation += drive.Name + "\n" + drive.DriveFormat + "\n" + "Drive total size: " + FormatBytes(drive.TotalSize) + "\n" + "Drive total free space: " + FormatBytes(drive.TotalFreeSpace) + "\n" + "Free space as percentage: " + result + "% \n ";
                    return driveInformation;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Fail";
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        return "Fail";
    }
```

**Writes info to console**

```
String[] Content  = new string[7]; 

        Content[0] = reportFunctions.GetOsName();
        Content[1] = reportFunctions.IsSoftwareInstalled();
        Content[2] = reportFunctions.CurrentLoggedInUser();
        Content[3] = reportFunctions.GetPcName();
        Content[4] = reportFunctions.CurrentDiskUsage();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 6)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Content[i]);
            i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: In what way does it fail to work? Does it give any errors?

Comment: this is a series of control-of-flow mistakes: you are exiting the `foreach` loop when you return `driveInformation`. then initialize it to null in every iteration of the loop before concatenating. finally overwriting with "Fail".

Comment: You just ignore if the drive is not ready? Have you debugged to see what drives are included in your `DriveInfo[]`? Have you examined the program flow to make sure it goes like you expected it to, iterating through the loop?  Seems like you've got some basic debugging steps you need to perform.

Comment: Sorry that would help wouldn't it, it fails by only reporting the info on the first drive (C:) none of the others that are attached (D:, E:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the first loop you have "`return "Fail";`"

Remove this line as it is blocking further effort.  You probably also want to remove the return from the exception as if your CD drive say drive D isnt ready your code will stop, and not continue too

EDIT: instead of the returns - as you also try to return a string of drive info - just write this data out to console.  Return means stop doing what Im doing now and go back to whatever ran me.

Your code needs to look more like this  (PS you should also use Environment.NewLine not \n as this always returns the correct linefeed for the OS)

```
public static string CurrentDiskUsage()
    {
        String driveInformation ="";   //your code overwrote this with each loop
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
        {
            try
            {

                if (drive.IsReady)
                {
                    double result = 100 * (double) drive.TotalFreeSpace / drive.TotalSize;
                    result = Math.Round(result, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                    driveInformation += drive.Name + Environment.NewLine + drive.DriveFormat + Environment.NewLine + "Drive total size: " + FormatBytes(drive.TotalSize) + Environment.NewLine + "Drive total free space: " + FormatBytes(drive.TotalFreeSpace) + Environment.NewLine + "Free space as percentage: " + result + "% "+Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                DriveInformation+="Fail:"+Drive.Name+Environment.NewLine+e.Message;
            }
        }

       return driveInformation;
    }
```

Comment: So i should remove the return from it completely?

Comment: @xjacksssss No. You should gather the results you want and then return all of them outside of the loop. Or look into the `yield` keyword.

Comment: Your control flow is wrong.  If any of the three returns are hit, the method will exit.  That does not sound like the intended flow.

Comment: Thanks guys will do a bit of playing with it.

Comment: Moved the return to the bottom in place of the bottom "return "fail";" and now works just as i wanted.  I have also initialized the variable `driveInformation` outside the if statement. Is this the best way to do this or have i just bodged it. Sorry if these seem like ridiculously stupid questions, i have only been self taught in my ventures with c# so might have some bad habbits.

Comment: you want it to always return fail as the results?

Comment: @BugFinder Nope,maybe i worded it badly but basically mine looks exactly as you put it above, thank you for the assistance, I see where i went wrong now